# class-validator with nestjs prevent creating missing fields with undefined when used with @IsOptional() decorator

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
export class UpdateXXXDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  field1: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  field2: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  field3: string;
}
```

As defined with an update request i am able to send a payload with only field1 as it is required, but for field2 and field3 i don't have to send them with the payload.
The problem i encountered is that when i send a payload with `{ "field1": "exp" }` i got a valid object but with `{ "field1": "exp", "field2": undefined, "field3": undefined }`.
I don't want that class-validator adds those optional fields at all ?

The documentation doesn't show any API to handle this case if i didn't miss anything! So i am asking the question to make sure if this is already possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue and finally found the solution. You need to ensure that `ValidationPipe` option `transformOptions.exposeUnsetFields` is set to `true` in combination with `transform: false`.

```js
 /** app is nest application object */
 app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: false,
      transformOptions: {
        exposeUnsetFields: false
      }
    })
 );
```

I did not found in the `nestjs` docs, but options defined within `transformOptions` are directly passed in the `plainToClass` function of the `class-transform` package.

From the related [docs](https://www.jsdocs.io/package/class-transformer#ClassTransformOptions.exposeUnsetFields):

> When set to true, fields with undefined as value will be included in
> class to plain transformation. Otherwise those fields will be omitted
> from the result.
>
> DEFAULT: true